# Is it legal Rust to cast a pointer to a struct's first member to a pointer to the struct?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

In C, a pointer to a struct can be cast to a pointer to its first member, and vice-versa. That is, the address of a struct is defined to be the address of its first member.

```
struct Base { int x; };
struct Derived { struct Base base; int y; };

int main() {
    struct Derived d = { {5}, 10 };
    struct Base *base = &d.base; // OK
    printf("%d\n", base->x);
    struct Derived *derived = (struct Derived *)base; // OK
    printf("%d\n", derived->y);
}
```

This is commonly used to implement C++-style inheritance.

Is the same thing allowed in Rust if the structs are `repr(C)` (so that their fields aren't reorganized)?

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
struct Base {
    x: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
struct Derived {
    base: Base,
    y: usize,
}

// safety: `base` should be a reference to `Derived::base`, otherwise this is UB
unsafe fn get_derived_from_base(base: &Base) -> &Derived {
    let ptr = base as *const Base as *const Derived;
    &*ptr
}

fn main() {
    let d = Derived {
        base: Base {
            x: 5
        },
        y: 10,
    };

    let base = &d.base;
    println!("{:?}", base);

    let derived = unsafe { get_derived_from_base(base) }; // defined behaviour?
    println!("{:?}", derived);
}
```

The code works, but will it always work, and is it defined behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way you wrote it, currently not; but it is possible to make it work.

Reference to `T` is only allowed to access `T` - no more (it has provenance for `T`). The expression `&d.base` gives you a reference that **is only valid for `Base`**. Using it to access `Derived`'s fields is undefined behavior. It is not clear this is what we want, and [there is active discussion about that](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/134) (also [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/256)), but that is the current behavior. There is a good tool named [Miri](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri) that allows you to check your Rust code for the presence of some (not all!) undefined behavior (you can run it in the playground; Tools->Miri), and indeed [it flags your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=99eda2084d5bb89b69c5aed113a55cb9):

```
error: Undefined Behavior: trying to reborrow <untagged> for SharedReadOnly permission at alloc1707[0x8], but that tag does not exist in the borrow stack for this location
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     &*ptr
   |     ^^^^^
   |     |
   |     trying to reborrow <untagged> for SharedReadOnly permission at alloc1707[0x8], but that tag does not exist in the borrow stack for this location
   |     this error occurs as part of a reborrow at alloc1707[0x0..0x10]
   |
   = help: this indicates a potential bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, but the rules it violated are still experimental
   = help: see https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/blob/master/wip/stacked-borrows.md for further information
           
   = note: inside `get_derived_from_base` at src/main.rs:17:5
note: inside `main` at src/main.rs:31:28
  --> src/main.rs:31:28
   |
31 |     let derived = unsafe { get_derived_from_base(base) }; // defined behaviour?
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can make it work by creating a reference to the whole `Derived` and casting it to a raw pointer to `Base`. The raw pointer will keep the provenance of the original reference, and thus [that will work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0893eb100a45005ea89d6e4c56d9dbf):

```rust
// safety: `base` should be a reference to `Derived`, otherwise this is UB
unsafe fn get_derived_from_base<'a>(base: *const Base) -> &'a Derived {
    let ptr = base as *const Derived;
    &*ptr
}

fn main() {
    let d = Derived {
        base: Base {
            x: 5
        },
        y: 10,
    };

    let base = &d as *const Derived as *const Base;
    println!("{:?}", unsafe { &*base });

    let derived = unsafe { get_derived_from_base(base) };
    println!("{:?}", derived);
}
```

**Note:** References should not be involved **at all** in the process. If you'll reborrow `base` as a reference of type `Base`, you will lose the provenance again. This will pass Miri on the playground, but is still undefined behavior per the current rules and will fail Miri with stricter flags (set the environment variable `MIRIFLAGS` to `-Zmiri-tag-raw-pointers` before running Miri locally).

Comment: Is the notion of passing of pointers to an inner object and then casting out based upon an inability to usefully handle things like the "Common Initial Sequence" guarantee even in cases where the cast reference/pointer will be the exclusive means of access to any parts of the object that are accessed at all through it and are modified during its lifetime?

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure I understand you: do you ask whether this is disallowed even when the pointer is exclusive? Yes.

Comment: In languages which support something like the Common Initial Sequence guarantee that was usefully present in C prior to C99, the normal paradigm would be to pass a pointer or reference to an outer object which would be cast to a type containing the common structure members.  Clang and gcc, however, interpret the Standard as forbidding such constructs, and the maintainers instead say that programs should put shared items in an inner type and cast to that, even if the function might need to use members of the outer type when passed an object of such a type.  For what reason would one *want*...

Comment: ...to pass a pointer to an inner object, rather than an outer one, and then convert to an outer type, other than to fit the type-access pattern that clang and gcc have decided to mandate?

Comment: @supercat Are you asking about the OP's C code or Rust code?

Comment: Language rules which exist solely for the purposes of optimization, and make it difficult for programmers to do what they need to do, are bad.  On the other hand, it's fine for language to forbid a particular way of doing something *if some other means would work just as well or better*.  An ability to pass pointers to a variety of structures to code can use the common parts interchangeably is useful; questions like the ones you linked about whether to support such constructs should depend upon why programmers would use them, and what alternatives would exist.

Comment: @supercat Rust doesn't have strict aliasing rules like C, and thus this is indeed not required. The main reason to disallow it is because it enables important optimizations, as mentioned in the discussions I linked; the main reason to allow it is because _people are doing it today_, and it is a common source of undefined behavior. Many of the usages indeed have an easy replacement, but the awareness wasn't high in the beginning and now it's hard to change that; many other are not so easy. In fact, one of the things this discussions do is bringing real-world examples.

Comment: Is there any reason a good language shouldn't provide a construct that would allow a means of saying "Within this block, objects identified using this pointer may be referenced in ways the compiler won't understand, and thus any actions performed within this block must be sequenced after any preceding actions using this pointer's base object and before any subsequent objects using this pointer's base object"?  Sure that would block "optimizations", but *that's the whole point*--if operations need to be done in a certain order, reordering them would be a breaking change, not an optimization.

Comment: @supercat You can have inline assembly to block compiler optimizations, however it's still UB in the Abstract VM. I don't know any language that provides such construct, and perhaps the reason is that if you need it your code is incorrectly designed - each language has its own way to dismiss some of the requirements of the pointers, and you're expectd to follow them (for example, use only raw pointers in this case).

Comment: If the machine code required to perform some useful task would be simple, a language which is suitable for such a task should not make it difficult.  Refusing to allow semantics because they would interfere with "optimization" is a form of premature optimization even worse than the kinds Knuth was warning about.  If a language can't allow a programmer to reliably achieve the required semantics, the speed with which generated code can perform a task incorrectly is irrelevant.

Comment: A language sacrifices the ease of use in the uncommon case to keep the common case faster. This is the same in C. High-level languages are not machine code, and the fact that the machine code for a particular problem is simple doesn't mean the code in the language will also be. You basically want a language without UB (at least temporally). But arguing about that here is useless; you can request the Rust designers (or the designers of any other programming language) to allow such thing, but I strongly doubt they'll accept that.

Comment: Making the less common case slightly harder is reasonable, but making it impossible isn't.  Knowing that everything that will be done with a raw pointer that's passed to a function will be done before that function returns is a relatively rare scenario which shouldn't require pessimization nearly as severe as a permanent pointer leak.

Comment: It is not impossible, just requires you to stay away from references. But again, I'm not the right person to tell that to. You're welcomed to open a thread on https://internals.rust-lang.org.